# Running NSLOOKUP against some urls to print out url that is not equals to some IPS i have

Tags: bash, shell, awk, nslookup

I have some Web URLs I am trying to do a `nslookup` against. All it does is check against the URL and print the ones not equals to some certain IP Address into a file. I am able to do it for one IP Address but i tried adding one more, and I am unable to get it to work.

```
SUB='.com'
for address in `cat linux.hosts`; do
  if [[ "$address" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
        echo "Got [$address]"
        nslookup $address \
        | awk '!/155.55.66.55/ || !/155.55.66.54/' >> com.txt
  fi
done
```

The `linux.hosts` file contains info like this

```
A B B { D E google.com }
A B B { D E twitter.com }
A B B { D E microsoft.com }
A B B { D E facebook.com }
```

I only want to get the string that has ".com" in it and do a nslookup that doesn't contain a certain IP Address.

The $nslookup address returns

```
Got [google.com]
Server:     BBBB:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB::1
Address:    BBBB:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 155.55.66.55
Name:   google.com
Address: 155.55.66.54
```

The `| awk '!/155.55.66.55/ || ' >> com.txt` works for some of the address that only contains 155.55.66.55 but if contains 155.55.66.54 it does not work, hence i am trying to add another check.

I only want to print the domains with address that doesn't contain
155.55.66.54 and 155.55.66.55.

The $nslookup address should only return

```
Got [twitter.com]
Server:     BBBB:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB::1
Address:    BBBB:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 198.168.101.1
Name:   google.com
Address: 198.168.101.2
```

Comment: Does your `cat` command break into lines properly? What is the output if you replace all the inner loop logic with just `echo $address`?

Comment: yes it does.

It returns something like this

Server:         1111:1111:1111:1111::1
Address:        1111:1111:1111:1111::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Name:   google.com
Address: 155.55.66.55

Comment: Sorry I meant with more than one line, what is the output then? Does it still work?

Comment: hello @EdMorton I only want to get the nslookup response that the address does not contain 155.55.66.55, 155.55.66.54 into the txt file.

The nslookup will always return responses like this 

Got [google.com]
Server:     BBBB:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB::1
Address:    BBBB:BBBB:BBBB:BBBB::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 155.55.66.55
Name:   google.com
Address: 155.55.66.54

Apologies if you aren't able to understand me still. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

[Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Also, probably redirect only once, after the loop, to avoid having the shell opening the file and seeking to the end repeatedly inside the loop.

As a minor optimization, use `grep` to find the matching lines in the file before the main loop.

```
grep -F '.com' linux.hosts |
while read -r _ _ _ _ _ _ address _; do
    nslookup "$address" |
    awk '!/155.55.66.55/ || !/155.55.66.54/'
done >>com.txt  # or maybe > com.txt if you want to overwrite
```

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to remove that line.

Comment: Its unable to run. In the linux.hosts file, It contains line

 A B C { D google.com }
 A B C { D facebook.com }
 A B C { D twitter.com }

hence why i am trying to use a substring on each line to get the one that contains ".com"

Comment: That's why we ask you to provide a [mre]